# Create Relationships from CSV file with UNWIND function

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc, csv-import

I need to create relationships between nodes I already created by importing correlation values from a CSV file. The file contains a column named 'sensor' whose values are sensor names (sensor_1, sensor_2...) and the remaining ones contain the correlation value. the file is structured as a square matrix. it would be great to avoid creating self-node relationships. I tried using apoc.do.when but it raises many errors, so I wrote down the following cypher code lines to try to get the relationships at least (self-node ones included), but it does not work, it just returns the sensor nodes. This is my first ever neo4j project and I'm stuck. Can you help me?

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///sensor_corr1.csv' AS row
MATCH (sensor:Sensor {id:toFloat(right(row['sensor'], 1))})
UNWIND [11, 12, 13, 15, 17, 2, 20, 21, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9] AS sensor_id
MATCH (sensor2:Sensor {id:sensor_id})
CALL {
WITH sensor_id, row
MERGE (sensor)-[corr:IS_CORRELATED_WITH {correlation:row['sensor_' + sensor_id]}]->(sensor2)
RETURN corr
}
RETURN sensor, corr
```

As explained in the details I'd like to get a link between al the sensor nodes with the correlation value as link property. In the best scenario I would like to know a way to avoid creating self-node relationship (Using apoc.do.when I failed).

Comment: pls give us a sample data in file:///sensor_corr1.csv. It is hard for me to imagine how it looks like. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @jose_bacoy, thanks for answering, I posted the image in the answer below

Answer (score 0):

it is a square matrix as I said and I need to build the link for each sensor with all the others by scanning the csv rows.
Here's the data: [sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5muF.png).
I found the answer: the problem was in the "match" clauses written outside the CALL:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///sensor_corr1.csv' AS row
UNWIND [11, 12, 13, 15, 17, 2, 20, 21, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9] AS sensor_id
CALL {
WITH sensor_id, row
MATCH (sensor:Sensor {id:toFloat(right(row['sensor'], 1))})
MATCH (sensor2:Sensor {id:sensor_id}) 
WHERE sensor.id <> sensor2.id
MERGE (sensor)-[corr:IS_CORRELATED_WITH {correlation:row['sensor_' 
+ sensor_id]}]->(sensor2)
RETURN sensor, corr
} 
RETURN sensor, corr
```